# Java RCP toolbar spoiled

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, rcp

The toolbar runaway from expected result the first button suppose located at the last button.. the rest of the button suppose display below the menu bar, this happening while change the eclipse version and currently i am using
eclipse luna 4.4.2
this line seem not helping

```
IToolBarManager toolbar = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT | SWT.LEFT);
```

[image]

In eclipse 3.7 those functions like openWorkbenchWindow (Workbench.class), restoreWorkbenchWindow will be call and end up to function like arrangeToolbar will be trigger

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc) Method declared on IWorkbench.
 */
public IWorkbenchWindow openWorkbenchWindow(final String perspID,
        final IAdaptable input) throws WorkbenchException {
    // Run op in busy cursor.
    final Object[] result = new Object[1];
    BusyIndicator.showWhile(null, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                result[0] = busyOpenWorkbenchWindow(perspID, input);
            } catch (WorkbenchException e) {
                result[0] = e;
            }
        }
    });
    if (result[0] instanceof IWorkbenchWindow) {
        return (IWorkbenchWindow) result[0];
    } else if (result[0] instanceof WorkbenchException) {
        throw (WorkbenchException) result[0];
    } else {
        throw new WorkbenchException(
                WorkbenchMessages.Abnormal_Workbench_Conditi);
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench#restoreWorkbenchWindow(org.eclipse.ui.IMemento)
 */
IWorkbenchWindow restoreWorkbenchWindow(IMemento memento)
        throws WorkbenchException {
    WorkbenchWindow newWindow = newWorkbenchWindow();
    newWindow.create();

    windowManager.add(newWindow);

    // whether the window was opened
    boolean opened = false;

    try {
        newWindow.restoreState(memento, null);
        newWindow.fireWindowRestored();
        newWindow.open();
        opened = true;
    } finally {
        if (!opened) {
            newWindow.close();
        }
    }

    return newWindow;
}


 void updatePerspectiveBar() {
    // Update each item as the text may have to be shortened.
    IContributionItem[] items = perspectiveBar.getItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].update();
    }
    // make sure the selected item is visible
    perspectiveBar.arrangeToolbar();
    setCoolItemSize(coolItem);
    perspectiveBar.getControl().redraw();

    if (getControl() != null)
        getControl().pack(true);
}
```

however, eclipse 4.4.2 does not contains above functions anymore
the functions contents are different and restoreWorkbenchWindow are no longer  support.

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc) Method declared on IWorkbench.
 */
@Override
public IWorkbenchWindow openWorkbenchWindow(String perspectiveId, IAdaptable input)
        throws WorkbenchException {
    IPerspectiveDescriptor descriptor = getPerspectiveRegistry().findPerspectiveWithId(
            perspectiveId);
    try {
        MWindow window = BasicFactoryImpl.eINSTANCE.createTrimmedWindow();
        return openWorkbenchWindow(input, descriptor, window, true);
    } catch (InjectionException e) {
        throw new WorkbenchException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public WorkbenchWindow openWorkbenchWindow(IAdaptable input, IPerspectiveDescriptor descriptor,
        MWindow window, boolean newWindow) {
    return (WorkbenchWindow) createWorkbenchWindow(input, descriptor, window, newWindow);
}
```

any advise or way to fix the issues i am facing? thanks you.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question

Comment: It is impossible to help when you provide so little information. Show us a [mcve]

Comment: i edited my question hope is understand to you.